# CQRS, Commands, Javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, cqrs

I have an architecture where a task-based UI passes commands to a service layer. Now, my intention is to implement the UI in javascript, using KendoUI and the service layer, domain layer etc. in .NET. I'm also looking at future mobile implementations of the client that may use say Java rather than Javascript.

If I define the commands in .NET, I'd like to know how to use them from my Javascript client so the client can communicate the commands appropriately to service layer. Do I have to use something like Apache Thrift for this i.e. to define the commands at both the client and service layer?

Comment: Yes you might. But be careful that the command you give as a dto from the server to the UI is not always the same as the one, you 'll send back from the UI to the server. The first one is the model of the page/UC/..., whereas the second one is the action you're trying to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use .NET have a look at this blog post I wrote, it uses t4 templates to render javascript objects of the C# Command/Query classes. The benefit from this is contract safty and code completion

http://andersmalmgren.com/2014/02/05/typed-javascript-contracts-using-t4-templates/

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer but I now use TypeScript on the client and I generate the corresponding typescript /ES6 classes as part of a build job.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a service layer implemented with .NET cab be exposed as an HTTP API with which JavaScript communicates. The HTTP API implementation can be regarded as an adapter in a [hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) which relays all requests to application services, which in turn invoke commands on your domain model.

You may use Thift as an interface definition language to declare the messages that flow between client and server. Given, that the client is JavaScript based, you'd want to the JSON protocol which Thrift has support for.